# Order Detail Query

Tags: sql-server

I tried to find a solution, but was unsuccessful. I have order header and order detail tables. I am trying to return all orders that have specific parts, but not others.

For example, return orders that have part A only, and explicitly exclude B and C.

Any help is really appreciated.

Sample Data:

[image: data table]

In this example, I want to return orders (OrderNumber and OrderLine) where part A is the only part on an order (10003).

Comment: Please provide some sample data and desired output as formatted text.

Comment: You have two examples posted and they conflict with each other. Or do you want order that have both A and B but not C OR orders with only A? I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Apologies for the conflicting examples, have corrected

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
select * from order where orderid in
(
   select orderid from order
   inner join orderdetail on order.orderid = orderdetail.orderid
   where orderdetail.partname in ('A', 'B')
)
and orderid not in 
(
   select orderid from order
   inner join orderdetail on order.orderid = orderdetail.orderid
   where orderdetail.partname in ('C')
)
```

Comment: This is not going to quite work currently. You would need to group by partname in the first subquery and then check for count(*) = 2

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT *
FROM Tbl t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Tbl
    WHERE t.OrderNumber = OrderNumber AND Part <> 'A'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this Query:

```
SELECT t.ordernumber, t.orderline
FROM test AS t
WHERE t.ordernumber NOT IN (SELECT ordernumber
                            FROM test 
                            WHERE part IN ('B','C'));
```

Output:

```
ordernumber | orderline
10003       | 1
```